# OpenBSD - PHP (chroot) - exec() cannot execute statically linked binary

Tags: php, exec, chroot, openbsd

I use OpenBSD and `PHP` for my private homepage. For the purpose of education (don't use this in production), I have to tried to execute a simple `Hello World` program in a `chroot`. Linked the binary statically. But I always get the result `127` (command not found).

How I execute the command in PHP:

```
<?php
    $output = null;
    $result = null;
    echo getcwd();
    exec("./foo", $output, $result);
    var_dump($output);
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

The program `./foo` definitely resides in the current working directory. Also the file permissions are correct.

The program in `C`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stdout, "foo: stdout");
    fprintf(stderr, "foo: stderr");
    return 42;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
$ cc -static -o foo foo.c
```

The output from PHP:

```
htdocs/example.org/www
array(0) {
}
int(127)
```

I would understand this behavior if the program is linked dynamically (missing shared libraries).

Is there a specific security feature enabled in the default configuration from OpenBSD which doesn't allow PHP to execute binaries or can somebody explain why this isn't working?

Also haven't disabled the function `exec()` in `/etc/php-8.0.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

In the default configuration from OpenBSD, `httpd` and `PHP` run in a `chroot`. The default directory `/var/www` will be used and there are only a few applications in `/var/www/bin`. Also the default shell is missing, unfortunately PHP's `exec` **requires** the shell. Therefore the error `127` (command not found).

A quick and dirty solution is to copy `/bin/sh` (which is statically linked) in the chroot:

```
$ cp /bin/sh /var/www/bin
```

Now PHP's `exec` command should work on OpenBSD.